# How can I get status of other Apps downloads in my Download Manager App?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to develop an app which can show the downloading status of all files.

e.g. someone start download an apk from Google play, i want to show the status of this file in my app.

Comment: you cannot the download status of files which are added to download from other apps as you dont know the download id of the file which is in download. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#enqueue%28android.app.DownloadManager.Request%29

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not implement the same. Normally Apps can not see each others data *(unless they intent to using content providers)*.

Many Apps like (App Lock etc.) can log the apps activity but I don't think you can intercept other apps downloads. This is the built in security feature in android. quoting from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Dalvik)

> Your application runs in a secure sandbox environment, so other processes on the system cannnot access your code or private data.